# how to get Image of same size after processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing, size, block

I am estimating ridge orientation of an fingerprint image by dividing it into blocks of 41*41..image is of size 240*320..here is my code and the problem is that I am getting output image size different than input image.

```
 % matalb code for orientation
    im =imread('D:\project\116_2_5.jpg');
    im = double(im);
    [m,n] = size(im);

    % to normalise image
    nor = im - mean(im(:));
    im = nor/std(nor(:));
    w = 41;

    % To calculate x and y gradient component using 3*3 sobel mask
    [delx,dely] = gradient(im);

    % Ridge orientation
     for i=21:w:240-41        
        for j=21:w:320-41     

            A = delx(i-20:i+20,j-20:j+20);
            B = dely(i-20:i+20,j-20:j+20); 

            Gxy = sum(sum(A.*B));
            Gxx = sum(sum(A.*A));
            Gyy = sum(sum(B.*B));
            diff = Gxx-Gyy;

            theta(i-20:i+20,j-20:j+20) = (pi/2) + 0.5*atan2(2*Gxy,diff);

        end;
    end;
```

but in this process i am loosing the pixels at the boundries so as to avoid the "index exceed" error i.e size of theta is m = 240-41 = 199 and n = 320-41=279..Thus my input image size is 240*320 and output image size is size 199*279..How can i get output image same as size of input image.
one more thing that i dnt have to use "blockproc" function...Thanks in advance

Comment: If you wanna map the original boundary pixels for theta, use this maybe? - 

theta1 = im;
theta1(21:size(theta,1),21:size(theta,2)) = theta;
theta = theta1;

Comment: Why blocks of 41 in the first place? Why not use blocks of 40 (which would fit neatly into your image size).

Comment: @nkjt block of 41 is used instead of 40 so as to get a center pixel of block..center pixel 21 has 20 pixel on either side and up down..u'll not get center in a block of 41

Comment: Does the algorithm require blocks with an odd number of pixels, or is that just a function of the way you're defining your loop, though?

Comment: @nkjt..ya it was my way of defining the loop..bt using a block of size 40*40 is good idea...thnks for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`padarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html) to add zeros onto your matrix:

```
A1 = padarray(A,[7 8],'post'); % 240+7=41*7, 320+8=41*8
B1 = padarray(B,[7 8],'post');
```

then generate `Gxx`, `Gyy`, and `Gxy` with `A1` and `B1`.

**Method 2:**

Besides, I tried to simplify your code a little bit by removing the loops, for your reference:

```
% Ridge orientation
Gxy = delx .* dely;
Gxx = delx .* delx;
Gyy = dely .* dely;

fun = @(x) sum(x(:))*ones(size(x));
theta_Gxy = blockproc(Gxy,[41 41],fun, 'PadPartialBlocks', true);
theta_diff = blockproc(Gxx-Gyy,[41 41],fun, 'PadPartialBlocks', true);

theta0 = pi/2 + 0.5 * atan2(2 * theta_Gxy, theta_diff);
theta = theta0(1:240, 1:320);
```

You may check [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) for more details.

Comment: what do you mean by code performance? It just added some zeros in order to make your matrix [41*7 41*8], since your elements in each 41*41 are all the same (sum of all the elements, then atan2 operation..), such a zero-padding won't influence on your orientation results.

Comment: ok..ok..i thought padding may result in difference in location of pixels..but padding worked very well..thanks..